# JAVA Springboot + spring security + JWT

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have been trying to create a basic spring-security + JWT application which asks for registration ('register') and then uses the same data from saved via register to sign-in '/sigin'. I created the following classes to register the user and then to test sign in. Unfortunately I am not able to register the user.

Any kind of guidance to nudge me towards the correct implementation would help me out. I am stuck at this currently

```
Entity Class


@Entity
public class ApplicationUser {

   public String user_name;
        @Id
     public String user_email;
     public String password;
     public String user_mobile;
     public String location;
 public String getUser_name() {
        return user_name;
    }
    public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
        this.user_name = user_name;
    }
    public String getUser_email() {
        return user_email;
    }
    public void setUser_email(String user_email) {
        this.user_email = user_email;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getUser_mobile() {
        return user_mobile;
    }
    public void setUser_mobile(String user_mobile) {
        this.user_mobile = user_mobile;
    }
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
    public ApplicationUser(String user_name, String user_email, String password, String user_mobile, String location) {
        super();
        this.user_name = user_name;
        this.user_email = user_email;
        this.password = password;
        this.user_mobile = user_mobile;
        this.location = location;
    }
    public ApplicationUser() {
        super();
    }
    public ApplicationUser(String user_name, String password) {
        super();
        this.user_name = user_name;
        this.password = password;
    }
    
    //    public Date user_dob;
    
}
---------------------------------------------------------------

Repsoitory 

public interface ApplicationUserRepository  extends JpaRepository<ApplicationUser, String>{
 

}
--------------------------------------------------------------

Service Class

@Service
public class ApplicationUserService {

  
  @Autowired
  private ApplicationUserRepository repository;

  public void registerUser(ApplicationUser user){
             
       repository.save(user);
  }
    
}


@Service
public class UserAuthService implements UserDetailsService  {

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationUserRepository repo; 

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    ApplicationUser appuser =  repo.findById(username).get();

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(appuser.getUser_email(), appuser.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>());
    }

     

}
-------------------------------------------------------------

JWTUTIL 

Component
public class JwtUtil {

   private String secret = "SecretKey";

    public String extractUsername(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }
    private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    }

    private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    public String generateToken(String username) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        return createToken(claims, username);
    }

    private String createToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {

        return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 10))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, secret).compact();
    }

    public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = extractUsername(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }
    
}
-------------------------------------------------

Configure

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ApiSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {



  @Autowired
  private JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtFilter;

  @Autowired  
  private UserAuthService userDetailsService;

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      
       auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder PasswordEncoder(){

    return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();

    }

    @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/signin", "/register")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
         
    }



}
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Controller


@RestController
public class ApplicationUserController {

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationUserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;
    
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   
    public String applicationUser(@RequestBody ApplicationUser user){
                
             userService.registerUser(user);
             System.out.println(""+user);

       return "Registraion successful";      
    }
 
    

  @PostMapping("/signin")
  public String generateToken(@RequestBody ApplicationUser authrequest) throws Exception{

    try{
          authenticationManager.authenticate( new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authrequest.getUser_email(), authrequest.getPassword())
          );
    }catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new Exception("inavalid username/password");
    }
        String userEmail = authrequest.getUser_email();

        return jwtUtil.generateToken(userEmail);

  }

    
}
```

Comment: I get it you are not able to register the user, so the login flow is working? Also, what kind of error are you having, while trying to register the user?

Comment: Hi @GregorioPalamà so far no error is coming up for register. Sign in is not working as well. What I was planning to do is to first register the user with details and then to sign in with those details. 
What I could understand for the register part is that the 'configure' method is not working as expected. 
...
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/signin", "/register")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
...

Comment: Here is a [JWT sample application](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/jwt/login) that demonstrates the concepts you are trying to implement on the JWT side. Note that the tutorial you're following is showing you how to build a custom JWT filter, but Spring Security already has this built-in. I'd also recommend building two separate projects, one for registration (no Spring Security, so you can practice Spring Data), and the other for JWT (so you can practice Spring Security). Put them together when they both work independently.

Comment: Did you check if the user's record is written into the database when the registration endpoint is called? Telling from the code, everything should work for the registration part...

Comment: `Unfortunately I am not able to register the user.` is a poor error description, literally 1000s of things may be wrong. It does not tell anything about what actually happens when you are doing "something". Please update your question with exact steps to reproduce (this including what requests you are doing and what they look like), what ACTUALLY happens when you do this, including the FULL debug logs, if you dont know how to get spring security debug logs, then use google.

Comment: When I am trying to go to "/register" api via postman, "403" error page is coming up, Same thing goes off with browser it loads me back to the default "/login" page of spring-security.
@GregorioPalamà No, it is not saving the users' record into the DB. As per my understanding it is not able to bypass spring-security login page for some reason.

Comment: So it seems your configuration has something that is not working. I'd start by disabling the configuration and checking if the registration flow is working. If it is, then I'd re-enable the configuration and try to figure out why it is leading to a 403 error, even if the /register endpoint should be permitted